# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript

Воспровожу пример из мануала Фланагана по JavaScript и получаю ошибку в Яндекс.Браузере (читай: Хроме):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation 
  Range.foreach /javascript/script.js:11
    (anonymous function)
```

В Safari тоже ошибка:

```
TypeError: Type error
```

Однако в Firefox ровно этот же код работает. Что это за ошибка и как поправить код?

Собственно код:

```
// Пример 9.2. Реализация класса Range с помощью конструктора (Фланаган: 224)

function Range(from, to) {
    this.from = from;
    this.to   = to;
}

Range.prototype = {
    foreach: function(f) {
        for(var x = Math.ceil(this.from); x <= this.to; x++)
            f(x);
    }
};

// Пример использования объекта range.
var r = new Range(1, 3);   // Создать новый объект range
r.foreach(console.log);    // Выведет 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну так попробуйте

```
r.foreach(function(x){console.log(x);});
```

Comment: Хороший вариант, работает.

Answer (score 5):

Как уже говорилось [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/226133/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation#answer-226158) и [там](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904782/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-in-javascript#answer-8904853).

Функция console.log обращает внимание на контекст this, пример:

```
var x = {};
x.func = function(){
    if(this !== x){
        throw new TypeError('Illegal invocation');
    }
    console.log('Hi!');
};

// Работает!
x.func();

var y = x.func;

// TypeError: Illegal invocation
y();
```

Соответственно получим ошибку `Illegal invocation`. Чтобы этого не происходило, вызовем эту функцию в нужном нам контексте:

```
y.call(x);
```

Вернемся к вопросу автора: в данном случае, так как, мы принимаем произвольную функцию, нельзя определить контекст внутри метода `foreach`. Но, можно привязать контекст к функци и передать уже связанную функцию так:

```
r.foreach(console.log.bind(console));
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция `console.log` хрома обращает внимание на контекст `this`, пример:

```
var log = console.log;
log('печенье');
```

Соответственно получим ошибку `Illegal invocation`. Чтобы этого не происходило, вызовем эту функцию в нужном нам контексте `console`:

```
log.call(console, 'печенье');
```

Ссылки:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904782/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-in-javascript

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612398/chrome-doesnt-recognize-console-log-when-its-called-log

Comment: Ага, про контекст this понятно. А вот как в данном коде этот .call() применить - не понятно.